# In R how to convert character strings to numeric in a dataframe

Tags: r, tidyr

I'd like to convert the values of a dataframe into a presence/absence matrix.
For example, changing this dataframe:

```
mat1<-rbind(c("ABY","ABY",NA,"ABY"),
      c("XWQ","RTY","RTY_U","XWQ"),c(NA,"UYT_W","WRT",NA),
      c("JUT",NA,NA,"JUT"))

as.data.frame(mat1)
rownames(mat1)<-c("A.1","A.2","B.1","B.2")
colnames(mat1)<-c("a","b","c","d"); mat1

    a     b       c       d    
A.1 "ABY" "ABY"   NA      "ABY"
A.2 "XWQ" "RTY"   "RTY_U" "XWQ"
B.1 NA    "UYT_W" "WRT"   NA   
B.2 "JUT" NA      NA      "JUT"
```

so that all NA elements are 0 and all non-NA elements are 1, thus mat1 is composed of only 1s and 0s. I'd be interested in a tidyverse solution.

Comment: `mat1[] <- +!is.na(mat1)`

Comment: wow fast! how do you make the elements numeric? thanks!

Comment: `mode(mat1) <- "numeric"`

Comment: Curious, why are you using `as.data.frame` there? It's not doing anything in the long run since you don't capture the return value.